# Not able to connect a Bluetooth Keyboard to an android device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, hid, rfcomm

I am trying to programmatically connect an Android phone to a Bluetooth device (which is already paired). I am using **createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID)** method in a thread.

I know the **Bluetooth keyboard is a HID device** so I am using UUID as

> **00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb**

The above method returns a BluetoothSocket object, but it fails to connect to the HID device, when bluetoothSocket.connect() is called. It gives **IOException: discovery failed**

I have searched about this a lot, but no clue how to fix this.

**Is it only possible to connect Rfcomm and not HID devices using this approach in Android?** If
so, then what alternate approach should I use for this? I am using Samsung Galaxy S3 with 
Android 4.1 in this application and after pairing (from settings) I could type using
the Bluetooth keyboard in some inbuilt apps like SMS, Email etc. It
seems to me that connecting to it should be possible, but I am not
sure if I am using the right approach. I want to read the keypress serial data in my app.

Here's the code which I am using:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread connection successful");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got it? To programmatically connect an android to a Bluetooth HID device? Same problem here now =/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is is only possible to connect Rfcomm and not HID devices using this approach in Android?

Yes, unfortunately. The naming of the java methods makes it quite clear that only rfcomm is supported. HID most likely operates on raw l2cap.

Try using [InputDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice.html) or [takeKeyEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#takeKeyEvents%28boolean%29) to get keypress data in your app.